# ¿Como instalar Moodle con IIS, PHP 7.2, MySQL? problema Moodle auth_oauth2 DDL sql execution error

Tags: mysql, php7, iis, moodle

Soy un simple estudiante y me dejaron de tarea instalar el servicio de **IIS**, `PHP`, `MySQL`, `Moodle`, he hecho todo lo necesario, configuré a lo que pude ver el php.ini di permisos a las carpetas, cree solo la carpeta de **moodledata**, iba bien pero al instalar me marca un error
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

rescato de eso que tengo que crear una base de datos, ya tengo una base de datos en `MySQL` y sé que existe por el command line, solo que en el workbench no sé cómo verla, no sé si se está usando. Gracias.

Comment: ¿Qué cosas has intentado para darle solución?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Que Versión de Moodle estas usando, por que de la version 3.8 para adelante se instala solo el moodledata y la base de datos. Solo que debemos tener cuidado en los permisos del host/moodle para que se puedan crear automáticamente.